# Import-csv and Filtering psobjects

Tags: powershell, csv

Im importing a csv ..I want to filter out rows if there is a $null value / zero(0) in length.
Im attempting like so..

```
$csv = Import-Csv $path | Where-object{ ($_.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {$_.length}) -eq 0}
```

I'm not getting the expected results however.

If I hone in on the knowing test faulty csv row (First row, row 0) with

```
$csv[0] | Select-Object 'Today Maximum Drawdown' 
($t.'Today Maximum Drawdown').length
```

I get a length of zero (0).

What am I missing?

Comment: "I want to filter out rows if there is a $null value / zero(0) in length" does this mean, if any of the cells of that row is empty?

Comment: Correct Santiago... Instead of filtering, column, by column, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to skip any row having an "empty cell", I would skip the part where you try to do it as a one-line:

```
@'
A, B, C
1, 2, 3
1,  , 3
 , 2,
1, 2, 3
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | ForEach-Object { $properties = $null } {
    # for the first object to process
    if (-not $properties) {
        # get the properties (Columns of the CSV)
        $properties = $_.PSObject.Properties.Name
    }

    foreach ($property in $properties) {
        if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.$property)) {
            return # skip this row
        }
    }
    # else, output it
    $_
}
```

If you want to do it with a `Where-Object`, which would make it harder to read, you could use `Enumerable.Any`:

```
@'
foo, bar, baz
1, 2, 3
1,  , 3
 , 2,
1, 2, 3
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | Where-Object {
    -not [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Any(
        $_.PSObject.Properties.Value,
        [Func[object, bool]] { [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($args[0]) })
}
```

Comment: This method works as expected!  Fantastic Santiago.  Thank you for your time.  Why do you think the one-liner didn't work?

Comment: @iceman so you're doing `$_.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object { $_.length }`, each `$_` in this case is a `PSNoteProperty` and the `.Length` value of these instances is always 1 no matter what. It seems that what you want to do was: `$_.PSObject.Properties.Value | ForEach-Object Length` then you would be getting the `Length` of each Value of each property. So for example: `Where-Object { ($_.PSObject.Properties.Value | ForEach-Object Length) -notcontains 0 }` should've worked